# How to determine the following statement is bilinear mapping or not?

Tags: bilinear-form

I have already checked wikipedia about bilinear mapping but still I haven't figured out how these things are working. Could anyone explain me?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[bilinear mapping or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWrWA.png)

Answer (score 0):

A function of two vectors in a vector space is *bilinear* if it is linear w. r. t. each of these vectors.

Two examples:

- The dot product in $\mathbf R^2$ or  $\mathbf R^3$.
- The cross-product.